# Latest Facebook Graph API > only admin user can login-upload photos

Tags: facebook-graph-api, air

I'm having an issue with a simple photo upload application whereby only 1 user can successfully login-upload images. 
Any other user (different Facebook account) and I get permissions errors **(user_likes,user_photos)**
Without getting code specific, does this sound like an application configuration issue?

With the latest changes in the facebookGraph API, is it now necessary to submit the app for FB review, even if this is a kiosk based application (ie will NOT be the app store or on the web).?

Which permissions are necessary to simply upload a photo? According to the documentation, anything more than ***public_profile***, ***email*** and ***user_friends*** requires submitting your app for review.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#review

In my FB Application's ***Status&Review>Status*** page I have made the application public and I see the green icon.

Part of the problem is that although iOS based, I am not using an official SDK (Adobe AIR) and also using a 3d party native Extension for interacting with Facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to go under Login Review if you app will be just used by it's admins/testers/developers.

If it will be used by other users than those and uses extended permissions, such as `publish_actions` for uploading photos, it's subject to review.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/#Creating