# Permissions needed to upload photo for a Facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

There seems to have been a huge change in the way Facebook manages apps that access their API. Now it seems if you want to create any app that allows uploads to Facebook this application MUST be reviewed by Facebook. Am I wrong? has anyone actually managed to speak or correspond DIRECTLY with anyone at facebook to confirm this?

So my question is, after a week of hair pulling and trying to get a simple image uploading application working, what permissions are necessary to upload a photo to facebook?

Right now I have
publish_actions
email
pubic_profile
user_friends

I'm guessing I ALSO need ***user_photo*** permissions.

But the convoluted process that is required to add more permissions has me stumped.
First i click new submission. Then I select user_photos. But I then get an error saying
 `'It looks like you haven't made any API requests to access content with the user_photos permission in the last 30 days. You need to test this permission in your app with any account listed in Roles before you can submit for review. It looks like you havent tested this permission because no API request has been made against publish_actions in the last 30 days.`

Which seems INCORRECT to me since in my signed GET request for image uploading I see the following

```
redirect_uri    fbconnect://success
display touch
state   {"is_open_session":true,"is_active_session":true,"com.facebook.sdk_client_state":true,"3_method":"fallback_auth","0_auth_logger_id":"foo"}
scope   ****user_photos****
```

Ok, can any Facebook API experts confirm that

1) I definitely need to submit my app for review in order to upload photos to a facebook account
2) I need user_photo permissions
and
3) I must first set up a test user and test with user_photos BEFORE I submit the app

***Addendum.*** After further testing am getting the image upload to work for all users, BUT only after logging in a 2nd time. ie after first login submit the user is presented with a new blank login popup. Only after logging in a 2nd time (the photo upload is done immediately after login) is the image uploaded successfully.

Can anyone suggest why this is happening? I've posted a 2nd question here
[Facebook Image Uploads-required to login twice for first upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31705739/facebook-image-uploads-required-to-login-twice-for-first-upload)

Comment: Yes on all questions

Comment: I guess further elaboration isn't necessary, but will approve if you answer instead of commenting. Any idea why I can't add user_photos for a new submission? ie the '.....looks like you haven't made any API requests to access content with the user_photos permission' error message

Comment: doesn't  "scope=user_photos" mean I AM making an API request with user_photos permission??

Comment: @WizKid The docs say otherwise concerning 2), see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/#Creating

Comment: Please see my addendum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be clear from the docs what is necessary and what not. I think I already answered questions 1) and 2) in your other question:

- [Latest Facebook Graph API > only admin user can login-upload photos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590423/latest-facebook-graph-api-only-admin-user-can-login-upload-photos)

I doubt that 3) is necessary, because according to the docs `user_photos` is needed to **retrieve** photos, and `publish_actions` to **upload** photos...

References:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/#Reading
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/#Creating

Comment: Tobi thanks.  But I am still stumped as to why 1)My application has been reviewed and approved with publish_actions, and 2) It still ONLY works with admin or any test users I set up. Can you think of any reason why this might be happening?

Comment: Concerning 2), what exactly do you mean with "not working"? What do you see as Login Window? Can you upload a screenshot?

Comment: please see my addendum

Comment: Must be something with your code I guess. As you don't show code here, it's impossbile to say.

Answer (score 3):

do this and you problem will solve 
go https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
select your Application and get access token and put this in field of submit "me/photos?fields=album" and press on submit  >
that is done . that requests API to access content with the user_photos permission ..
Also can do that for every permission need to API requests  just with some chage ...etc