# Facebook Image Uploads-required to login twice for first upload

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a simple kiosk based application that enables users to upload photos to their facebook pages. Everything works and I've had the application reviewed approved by facebook since it requires 'publish_actions' for image uploads.

However, for the first upload, the user needs to login a 2nd time (see below). Ideally what I need to happen is go directly from screen 1 first login to screen 4 or at the very least bypass the 2nd login. Can any facebook API experts suggest a solution?
Could this be something the application advanced settings?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080255/facebook-publish-action-permission-not-working-for-posting  For me the important part was 'Make sure you have at least one action and one object set up in the open graph section'

Comment: That doesn't sound right. It should go from 1->2->4. Do you have somewhere we can test this?